How to prove that all elements inside a cycle of a cyclic group are different from each other

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group $(G, \circ)$ and $a \in G$:
$$
\langle a \rangle = \{a^z : z \in \mathbb{Z}\}, 
$$
and $\operatorname{ord}(a) = \min\{a^n : n \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$, i.e., the smallest integer $n$ with $a^n = e$, where $e$ is the neutral element.

So we have:
$$
\langle a \rangle = \{a^1, a^2, a^3, ..., a^n\}.
$$
How can we prove that all elements of a cycle truely have different values, i.e., no element has the same value as another element?
Thank you very much for your answer in advance.
I have tried $a^i$ and $a^j$ with 1 < i < j < n and $a^i$ = $a^j$
$$
a^j = a^i \circ a^{(j-i)}
\Rightarrow a^{(j-i)} = e
$$
However (j - i) can have very different values depending on i and j.
If i < j/2  $\Rightarrow (j-i) > i $ --> You would have proven that $a^i$ and $a^j$ are not in the same cycle since there is the neutral element e in between them, and you have shown  that n is not the smallest integer for which $a^n = e$, which means ord(a)${}\neq{}$n, if $a^i$ = $a^j$.
If i > j/2 $\Rightarrow (j-i) < i$ --> This time e is not in between of $a^i$ and $a^j$ --> but you have proven that n is not the smallest integer for which $a^n = e$, which means ord(a)${}\neq{}$n, if $a^i$ = $a^j$.
If i = j/2 $\Rightarrow a^i = a^{(j-i)} = e \Rightarrow a^j = e $  --> You have shown that $a^i$ and $a^j$ would be equal to e, which again means that n is not the smallest integer for which $a^n = e$, so ord(a)${}\neq{}$n, if $a^i$ = $a^j$.
I honestly don't know how to continue or interpret my results. Is this proof that all values generated from a^1 to a^n must be different?
Sorry, I am not a seasoned mathematician, even not a math student.

If it were me, I would start by assuming that there are two equal elements, say $a^m = a^n$ with $m \neq n$. Then find a contradiction.

Please, use MathJax consistently instead of using unusual characters as ∘ and ∈ that won't render properly in many devices.

Your formula for $\langle a \rangle$ doesn't make sense, as it is meant to be the subgroup generated by $a$, which is in particular a set of elements, e.g.,
$$
\langle a \rangle = { 1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{n-1} }
$$
if the order of $a$ is $n$.

@SammyBlack;
Thanks for your comment. As I am now saying in my question, I am not a mathematician. So please bear with me.
My question now says
$ \langle a \rangle = {a^1, a^2, a^3, ..., a^n} $
I think that is correct. I would not write 1 since I have not predetermined what the operation is. Neutral element could be 0 as well.
I think it is also okay to write $ \langle a \rangle $ in this way and it is for me easier to understand a "cycle" going from a to e and not from e to $a^{(n-1)}$

Here is the standard way to see this.
Suppose that $n = ord(a)$, so $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^n = e$.
Then note the following:

(*) $a^k = e$ if and only if $n$ divides $k$.

Here is the proof: Suppose that $a^k = e$. By the division algorithm, write $k = qn+r$ with $0 \leq r < n$. Since $a^n = e$, we get $a^k = a^{qn+r} = (a^n)^q a^r = a^r$, so $a^r = e$. But because $n$ is the smallest positive integer with $a^n = e$, we must have $r = 0$. So indeed $n$ divides $k$.
Conversely if $n$ divides $k$, it is easy to see that $a^k = e$, and I leave this to you.
Now for your question: as you have seen, $a^i = a^j$ implies $a^{i-j} = e$. So by (*), this implies that $n$ divides $i-j$. For $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ this can only happen when $i = j$.
